# Finding a house with the largest area and returning who lives there (no pandas)

Tags: python, csv, multiple-columns, area

I am new to python and am struggling with this code. I have a csv file and am trying to create a function. The file, personal_info.csv , has a few columns with one labeled house_area and one named full_name. I am trying to create a code that will find the house with the largest area and return the name of person who owns it.

I am also not allowed to import anything besides the csv file, so I cannot use pandas.

Here's what some of the data looks like:

| house_area | full_name |
| --- | --- |
| 40.132 | John Smith |
| 85.832 | Anna Lee |
| 38.427 | Emma Jones |

So in this small sample I'm trying to find the house with the largest area (85.832) and print the person's name, Anna Lee. Except the actual file has a lot more rows

Comment: Please consider showing the code you have tried out. Add it as text, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Read and iterate over each row in the csv and check if the current value is bigger than the current biggest and update the value if its true:

```
import csv

with open("personal_info.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    max_area = 0
    max_name = ""

    for row in reader:
        area = float(row["house_area"])
        if area > max_area:
            max_area = area
            max_name = row["full_name"]

    print(max_name)
```

If there are two house which got the same size, than the name of the first one is returned.

Comment: Thank you! I have a question - I can't copy and paste the file name because it has these weird characters following the name, do you know how I would store it as the index value of the column? If that would work with this code?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean with index value of the column. Which column? Can you be a bit more specific, a little example maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) by using [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.reader) and [`max`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
import csv
​
with open("personal_info.csv", "r") as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    max_row = max(csv_reader, key=lambda row: float(row[0]))

# Output​
print(max_row)​
['85.832', 'Anna Lee']
```

Comment: He said he can not use pandas.

Comment: Oops, I removed the `pandas` approach. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

One simple way you can do this is by creating a variable called to track the largest house area. Let's call this `largest_area` and set it to the value `0` (assuming all house areas in your CSV are greater than 0).

Then using, the csv library, go through each row in the CSV file, grab the house_area, and compare it to the `largest_area` variable you created. If it is greater, update `largest_area`, otherwise ignore and continue through the CSV file.

After you have finished going through the CSV file, the greatest area should be in your `largest_area` variable.